# Generating Sequence of Right angled triangle

Tags: triangles, generating-functions, sequence-of-function, pythagorean-triples

A "nearly isoceles" right-angled triangle with integer side lengths is defined as one in which the two sides adjacent to the right angle differ in length by just 1 unit. A triangle with side lengths 20,21 and 29 is an example. Find with proof , a method for generating a sequence of such triangles.
I do not have my work because I cannot understand that how can I approach this problem or what is the strategy to solve it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number Theory involving Pythagorean triplets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2405519/number-theory-involving-pythagorean-triplets)

Answer (score 2):

$\textbf{Matching the difference} \quad X=|B-A|$

There are $\space3\space$ approaches we can take for this:

$X$ can be any prime number $(p)$ where $p\equiv\pm1\mod 8$ with (p) raised to any non-negative power. Under $100$,  $X\in \{1,7, 17, 23, 31, 41, 47, 49, 71, 73, 79, 89, 97\}$.

1. Beginning with $X=1$, a solution was provided by Wacław Sierpiński $\quad$[Pythagorean triangles,
   THE SCRPTA MATHEMATICA STUDIES Number NINE,
   GRADUATE SCHOOL OF SCIENCE YESHIVA  UNIVERSITY, NEW YORK, 1962, pp.  17-22
   ]$\quad$  with equations that resolve to the following for generating these triples $(T_n)$ in sequence with a starting "seed" of $T_0=(0,0,1)$.
   \begin{equation}
   A_{n+1}=3A_n+2C_n+1\\  
   B_{n+1}=3A_n+2C_n+2 \\
    C_{n+1}=4A_n+3C_n+2\\
   \
   T_1=(3,4,5)\quad T_2=(20,21,29)\\ T_3=(119,120,168)\quad T_4=(696,697,985)
   \end{equation}

We can use Euclid's formula shown here as
$$
A=m^2=k^2\quad B=2mk\quad C=m^2+k^2
$$

2. and we can find the $\space (m,k)\space$ numbers to feed the formula with the following equation where
   $\space k\space$ begins at $\space1\space$ and each
   $\space m\space$ found becomes $\space k\space$ for the next iteration.
   $$m=k+\sqrt{2k^2+(-1)^k}$$
   \begin{align*}
   k=1\space& m=1+\sqrt{2(1)^2+(-1)^1}=2 & F(2,1)=(3,4,5)\\
   k=2 \space& m=2+\sqrt{2(2)^2+(-1)^2}=5 & F(5,2)=(21,20,29)\\
   k=5 \space& m=5+\sqrt{2(5)^2+(-1)^5}=12 & F(12,5)=(119,120,169)\\
   k=12 \space& m=12+\sqrt{2(12)^2+(-1)^{12}}=29 & F(29,12)=(697,696,985)
    \end{align*}

The series $\{0, 1, 2, 5, 12, 29, 70, 169, ...\}$ are Pell numbers

3. and the $(m,k)$-values  needed of them may be generated directly using the following:
   $$ m_n= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^{n+1} - (1 - \sqrt{2})^{n+1}}{2\sqrt{2}}\\
    k_n= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^n - (1 - \sqrt{2})^n}{2\sqrt{2}}$$
   For example
   \begin{align*}
   m_1= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^{2} - (1 - \sqrt{2})^{2}}{2\sqrt{2}}=2 &
        \quad k_1= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^1 - (1 - \sqrt{2})^1}{2\sqrt{2}}=1
   \\& F(2,1)=(3,4,5)\\    
   m_2= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^{3} - (1 - \sqrt{2})^{3}}{2\sqrt{2}}=5&
        \quad k_2= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^2 - (1 - \sqrt{2})^2}{2\sqrt{2}}=2
   \\& F(5,2)=(21,20,29)\\
    m_3= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^{4} - (1 - \sqrt{2})^{4}}{2\sqrt{2}}=12&
        \quad k_3= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^3 - (1 - \sqrt{2})^3}{2\sqrt{2}}=5
   \\& F(12,5)=(119,120,169)\\ 
    m_4= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^{5} - (1 - \sqrt{2})^{5}}{2\sqrt{2}}=29&
        \quad k_4= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^4 - (1 - \sqrt{2})^4}{2\sqrt{2}}=12
   \\& F(29,12)=(697,696,985)
    \end{align*}

Comment: Nice and complete.

Comment: And a duplicate of answer by same user at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2405519/number-theory-involving-pythagorean-triplets

Answer (score 1):

Remember that a Pythagorean triangle
with relatively prime legs
has sides
$2mn, m^2-n^2, m^2+n^2
$
for some integers $m$ and $n$.

If the legs are
$a$ and $a+1$,
since they are
relatively prime,
the legs must satisfy
either
$a=2mn, a+1=m^2-n^2$
or
$a=m^2-n^2, a+1=2mn$.

Find the solutions
to these equations
and you will have your triangles.